# Prevent BODY from scrolling when a modal is opened in angular application

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, bootstrap-modal

I want my body to stop scrolling to top when I am trying to open popup modals. I am using both angular material and `ng-bootstrap` popup modals.

I've tried the piece of CSS code below, but the issue is still there, please help.

```
body.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the modal prevents the body scrolling by default. You must have some code that overwrites it. Could you provide your code please?

Comment: please check https://css-tricks.com/prevent-page-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-open/

Comment: That is an edge case. Please provide your code or we will not be able o help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220831/how-to-change-the-position-of-modals-in-ng-bootstrap) the position of the modal is set to default at the top.  To completely remove the scrolling, use that to position the modal down.  If you just want to be at the same position after the modal close, you can use this which I used from the comments: [here](https://css-tricks.com/prevent-page-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-open/)

```
  openModal() {
    // Remember the current scroll position
    let pos = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalComponent);
     this.modalHideSubscription = this.modalService.onHide.subscribe(() => {
      //Return back to the position before opening modal
      window.scrollTo(0,pos);
      this.modalHideSubscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
```